# SQL Oracle HRMS

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select   ppf.employee_number , ABA.absence_days 
from     PER_ABSENCE_ATTENDANCES ABA, apps.PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F ppf
where    ppf.person_id = aba.person_id
```

I need to get **all** employee numbers and absence days under under their manager (`parent_position_id` & `subordinate_position_id` in table `per_pos_structure_elements`)

e.g `parent_position_id = 12541`

How can I integrate them?

Comment: Human Resources Management System I guess.

Comment: That is Oracle default HR schema?

Comment: @FlorinGhita it's Oracle E-Business Suite (Human Resources Management System) and my question about the DB of it

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
select   ppf.employee_number , ABA.absence_days 
from     PER_ABSENCE_ATTENDANCES ABA
inner join apps.PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F ppf
   on ppf.person_id = ABA.person_id
inner join per_pos_structure_elements
   on ppf.subordinate_position_id = ppf.person_id
where    ppf.parent_position_id = 12541
```

Comment: @littlegreen Not like This but thank you any way :) Because person_Id value not equal to subordinate_position_id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT employee_number, NVL(a.absence_days,0)
FROM (SELECT ppf.employee_number employee_number , ABA.absence_days absence_days
      FROM apps.PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F ppf
      LEFT OUTER JOIN PER_ABSENCE_ATTENDANCES ABA ON ppf.person_id = ABA.person_id
     ) a
INNER JOIN per_pos_structure_elements pps
   ON pps.subordinate_position_id = ppf.person_id AND ppf.parent_position_id = 12541
```

Comment: person_Id value not equal to subordinate_position_id and thank you any way